# strange issue during magento site transfer to localhost

Tags: magento, error-handling

> I need to set-up a site on my local system from the live site
>
> . The site is filed with lot of extensions and have a **catalog** of
>   more than 1lakh.
>
> The magento is running now on my local
>
> .But when i click on any category or link it shows 404 error.
>
> I need to manually add index.php than the URL works fine.
>
> But if I add index.php in core config table it **hangs** my
>   **system**

.

Please suggest me what can be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to apache web server rewrite module.
Go to admin configuration and  Set Use Web Server Rewrites to no in your local environment or enable Apache web server’s mod_rewrite module .